# Ordering list of image file names as numbers not as strings (on Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, image, mediastore

For an Android app I'm building (Android 4.0.3), I'm trying to get a list of image file names situated in a folder on the local storage. This is working accurately, however, my images are listed in the wrong order - they are ordered as strings, and I need them to be ordered as numbers (since my file names contain numbers, not characters/words. They are named like this: 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc. - all the way up to 11.jpg, 12.jpg etc. However, the list that is returned using the function below is ordered as 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 11.jpg, 12.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, etc. That's not good, I need the list to be ordered as logical numbers, not as a string.

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks so much!

```
public BitmapProvider2() 
            {
                     Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                     String selection = Images.Media.DATA+" LIKE ?";
                     String[] selectionArgs = {mCurrentDir+"%"};   
                     final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE;
                     mImageCur = managedQuery(uri, null, selection, selectionArgs,orderBy );
                     if (mImageCur == null) 
                         return;
                    // int column_index = mImageCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                     mImageCur.moveToFirst();
                     mImagesCount = mImageCur.getCount();
            }
```

Comment: check this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705332/how-to-sort-files-using-datetimestamp-or-counter-values

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is returning like that is because your file name is a String not numbers. So 11.jpg will go before 2.jpg.

In order to fix this, you can sort it after you take it out by using Compareable comparator, then use Collections.sort(); , and/or you can trim out the '.jpg' and parse as int, then sort.

Comment: check this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705332/how-to-sort-files-using-datetimestamp-or-counter-values